# How can we convert between a program using `call/cc` and a program using functions written in CPS?

Tags: scheme, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

The Scheme Programming Language says

> It turns out that any program that uses call/cc can be rewritten in CPS without call/cc, but
>   a total rewrite of the program (sometimes including even system-defined primitives) might be necessary.

What are the general techniques to

- convert a program using `call/cc` to a program using functions written in CPS
- convert in the reverse direction?

Comment: I first learned about the CPS transform from these slides http://churchturing.org/y/90-min-scc.pdf - it transforms source code in lambda calculus + call/cc to plain lambda calculus. It does this by adding a continuation parameter to every procedure and making each procedure invocation pass in a continuation.

Comment: the intent is, you convert *any* program into CPS. *then*, call/cc becomes trivial, in the converted program. -- `(call/cc (lambda (k) ...))` ==> `(call/cc& (lambda (k) ...) k)` == `((lambda (k) ...) k)`. i.e. `(define (call/cc& lam k) (lam k))` is the definition. that's the simple story; I think there were some recent posts about the call/cc implementation in CPS, in [tag:scheme], try searching for them.

Comment: actually, it should've been `(call/cc (lambda (k) ...))` ==> `(call/cc& (lambda (k c) ...) c)` == `((lambda (k c) ...) c c)`. i.e. `(define (call/cc& lam c) (lam c c))` (under the scheme where the continuation is always passed as the last argument (which is of course an arbitrary choice)).

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to implement the continuation passing transform here http://matt.might.net/articles/cps-conversion/ or from the book Compiling With Continuations by Appel.

The reverse transform is more difficult and has less practical applications but there is a paper about it: [Back to Direct Style (1994) by Olivier Danvy](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.7604)